# Create a ethernet packet in a kernel module and send it

Tags: linux, networking, module, kernel

I need to create an ethernet packet an send it in my kernel module. Someone can help me to do this?

I think i need to create a skb using dev_alloc_skb, then i need to write the mac_ethernet, insert the data and send it using dev_queu_xmit.

But i'm not sure if this work, or if it is the right and easiest way to do it.

Best Regards

EDIT1:

```
int sendpacket ()
{
    unsigned char dest[ETH_ALEN]={0x00,0x25,0x22,0x05,0xF3,0xF0};
    unsigned char src[ETH_ALEN] = {0x90,0xE6,0xBA,0x48,0x7C,0x87};

struct sk_buff * skbt =alloc_skb(ETH_FRAME_LEN,GFP_KERNEL);      
//skb_reserve(skb,ETH_FRAME_LEN);


dev_hard_header(skbt,dev_eth1,ETH_P_802_3,dest,src,dev_eth1->addr_len);

if(dev_queue_xmit(skbt)!=NET_XMIT_SUCCESS)
{
    printk("Not send!!\n");
}



kfree_skb(skbt);
return 0;
```

}

```
> Dmesg command:
> 
>  677.826933] Hello:I'm the hook module!!!! [  677.826937] 2!!!! [  677.826941] skb_under_panic: text:c0723608 len:14 put:14 head:f1843800 data:f18437f2 tail:0xf1843800 end:0xf1843e00 dev:<NULL> [  677.826959]
> ------------[ cut here ]------------ [  677.826961] kernel BUG at net/core/skbuff.c:146! [  677.826964] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP  [
> 677.826967] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cache/index2/shared_cpu_map [ 
> 677.826969] Modules linked in: sendpacket(+) bluetooth rfkill vfat fat fuse sunrpc cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq mperf ip6t_REJECT
> nf_conntrack_ipv6 ip6table_filter ip6_tables ipv6 uinput
> snd_hda_codec_atihdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel
> snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm snd_timer snd
> soundcore atl1e snd_page_alloc iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support r8169 mii
> i2c_i801 microcode asus_atk0110 pcspkr ata_generic pata_acpi
> usb_storage pata_marvell radeon ttm drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit
> i2c_core [last unloaded: sendpacket] [  677.827003]  [  677.827003]
> Pid: 4780, comm: insmod Tainted: G        W   2.6.35101 #7 P5QL
> PRO/P5QL PRO [  677.827003] EIP: 0060:[<c070a192>] EFLAGS: 00210246
> CPU: 0 [  677.827003] EIP is at skb_push+0x57/0x62 [  677.827003] EAX:
> 00000088 EBX: c08f9fdc ECX: f156bf10 EDX: c093b4ca [  677.827003] ESI:
> 00000000 EDI: f51ca000 EBP: f156bf38 ESP: f156bf0c [  677.827003]  DS:
> 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068 [  677.827003] Process insmod
> (pid: 4780, ti=f156a000 task=f2b071a0 task.ti=f156a000) [  677.827003]
> Stack: [  677.827003]  c093b4ca c0723608 0000000e 0000000e f1843800
> f18437f2 f1843800 f1843e00 [  677.827003] <0> c08f9fdc f156bf64
> f156bf6a f156bf50 c0723608 00000001 c07235e5 f3b6c000 [  677.827003]
> <0> 00835ff4 f156bf78 f7d640a8 f156bf6a f156bf64 00000006 48bae690
> 2500877c [  677.827003] Call Trace: [  677.827003]  [<c0723608>] ?
> eth_header+0x23/0x93 [  677.827003]  [<c0723608>] ?
> eth_header+0x23/0x93 [  677.827003]  [<c07235e5>] ?
> eth_header+0x0/0x93 [  677.827003]  [<f7d640a8>] ?
> sendpacket+0x8f/0xb6 [sendpacket] [  677.827003]  [<f7d67000>] ?
> hook_init+0x0/0x46 [sendpacket] [  677.827003]  [<f7d67044>] ?
> hook_init+0x44/0x46 [sendpacket] [  677.827003]  [<c0401246>] ?
> do_one_initcall+0x4f/0x139 [  677.827003]  [<c0451e29>] ?
> blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x11/0x13 [  677.827003]  [<c046210c>] ?
> sys_init_module+0x7f/0x19b [  677.827003]  [<c040321f>] ?
> sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28 [  677.827003] Code: c0 85 f6 0f 45 de 53
> ff b0 a8 00 00 00 ff b0 a4 00 00 00 51 ff b0 ac 00 00 00 52 ff 70 50
> ff 75 04 68 ca b4 93 c0 e8 ad 4a 09 00 <0f> 0b 8d 65 f8 89 c8 5b 5e 5d
> c3 55 89 e5 56 53 0f 1f 44 00 00  [  677.827116] EIP: [<c070a192>]
> skb_push+0x57/0x62 SS:ESP 0068:f156bf0c [  677.827154] ---[ end trace
> dee1e3278503a581 ]---
```

Comment: Roughly speaking your approach sounds valid. Beware though, that sending packets from the kernel is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to create a message to configure a machin. I use a pre-defined ethernet type and i want to insert the data in the payload. What is the best way do it? If you could supply a basic code example i appreciate. Thank You.

Comment: In that case you're much better off using raw packets from user space.

Comment: But the ideia is to do that at the kernel module.

Comment: Don't. Do everything possible from user space.

Comment: See this question and the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245281/using-sk-buff-to-add-an-ethernet-frame-header

Comment: Can you check my edit 1? If i understand the other topic, i just need to alloc a skb and because i just need an ethernet frame, the function dev_hard_heard makes the heard and it's done? A segmentation fault happens, what can be? I call this function when i inser the module.

Comment: As u are providing the source code, it seems that u are only making ethernet header but there is no code for network & transport layer header. so if u can provide the actual code or full code then it will be helpfull to get the actual problem occuring.... if this is the reason then u have to create these headers with relevant info & then try to send it.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you just want to use raw packets from user space instead of dealing with the complexities of kernel code.

This [blog post](http://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/) details how to do everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding like a broken record you're learning **why** this should be done from user space.

Because you seem determined to make this mistake anyway, let's try to figure out what the problem is.

It's also a good illustration of how helpful it is to have source code. The exception log tells you the problem occurred on line 146 of net/core/skbuff.c.
That's within the function `skb_under_panic()`, which is only used in that file (it's static after all), from within `skb_push()`.

The `skb_push()` function expands the skb forwards. Basically it creates room in the buffer for a new header. It does this by shifting the internal `data` pointer forward.

In your case, the internal `data` pointer is still in its original localtion: at the very from of the skb. You need to reserve some room at the front of the skb first. Use `skb_reserve()`, pretty much just like you had. Why did you comment that out?

Also, you need to check that the allocation of the skb succeeded. Kernel allocators can (and **do**) return NULL sometimes.

Comment: I coment skb_reserve because i the other post, they just reserved headersroom space for others heardes, not for the ethernet. I uncoment that line but the process is Killed : access null point at 0x000000c. I have a kernel module that forwards some kinds of packet based on eth.type, and now i want had there a a configuration packet when a packet of some protocol arrives, and that why i want to do this at kernel level.

Comment: Did you do skb_reserve(skb, ..) or skb_reserve(skbt, ...)?

Comment: I did skb_reserve(skbt,ETH_HLEN). The function dev_hard_hearder return the value 14. When i try to send the skb, the kernel crashes.

Comment: Try adding some payload to your packet (and an Ethernet type). I wouldn't be surprised if some network drivers don't like ethernet packets without payload. If that doesn't help post the crash.

Comment: I added the payload but the kernel crashs and i can't find error. I solve my problem creating a skb buffer and then complete all the fiels one by one:ethernet header,skb->mac_header,skb->data, skb->dev an now i can create and send some packets.